# Unable to connect to gmail smtp linode django apache2 setup

Tags: django, smtp, gmail, apache2, linode

Hello im having difficulties connecting to google smtp server. The context is that whenever a user fills in a form , my program will automatically email me the feedback to my gmail account. Everything is working except for the fact that the program is stuck within the send_mail function.

I have tried doing this :

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
Trying 2404:6800:4003:c03::6c...
```

Which will eventually result in a time out.

Here is some of my code:

## settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxx'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True                                                                                                                  
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER                                                                                                  
SERVER_EMAIL = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
```

As per out of the box from wagtail(django cms package)

I thought it might have to do with my UFW blocking it  , however i have tried disabling the UFW and restarting apache2 . This unfortunately does not help.

## ufw status

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I am really lost! Please help . Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newly created Linode accounts restrict the use of mailing ports (25, 465, and 587) by default.

> In an effort to fight spam, new Linode accounts created after Tuesday, 5 November, 2019 have mailing ports (25, 465, and 587) restricted by default (see our blog post [here](https://www.linode.com/blog/linode/a-new-policy-to-help-fight-spam/) for more information).

However, If you would like to use your Linodes for sending emails, you will first need to configure :

1. a valid DNS A record and
2. rDNS for any Linodes that you plan to use to send emails.

You can see how to do that here: [[source]](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/19082/i-just-created-my-first-linode-and-i-cant-send-emails-why)

Comment: Thanks so much @Hisam, I was stuck in this issue for a day. In fact, I just gave up and raised a ticket to linode & now I confirm this was it.